# (Supported)MapFragment lifecycle calls

Tags: android, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I am just starting to use MapFragment (or actually SupportedMapFragment as I'm targeting API 8). I never used MapView (V1) in the past.

What I notice is that on MapView one was told to make the lifecycle calls (onPause() etc) from the Activity, but there is nothing documented about doing that in (Supported)MapFragment, although it does appear to have the same methods as MapView.

Does one have to or not?

Comment: Are you really using Android Maps API v1 ? You should start with v2 instead in my opinion.

Comment: I am using V2. Just wanted to know about the Fragment lifecycle calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragment`s handle their own lifecycle, which is one of the things that's really nice about them. If you're asking whether you have to explicitly call `onResume`, `onPause`, etc... on a `MapFragment`, the answer is no.

The point of `Fragment`s is to have modular pieces of UI that you can drop into different parts of the app. For example, you could have a map fragment and a list fragment that you toggle between on phones, but have both of them side by side on tablets.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I hoped. What are they there for, then?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

in the case of a **MapFragment**, you have **onMapReady()** before **onPause()**.

[image]